# Assigning image to image control in iText Java library

Tags: java, itext, openoffice.org

I'm using iText library to generate PDF based on a template in java application. I have created the template using Open Office. I'm using image control in my template, my question is how to assign an image to image control through java code.Is there any method like `stamper.getAcroFields().setField(String,String)` for image control?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to use PushbuttonField and assign image to it.Following is the code for it-

```
PushbuttonField ad = form.getNewPushbuttonFromField("imgPush");
ad.setLayout(PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY);
ad.setProportionalIcon(true);
ad.setImage(Image.getInstance("C:/Users/nikhil_kshirsagar/Downloads/images.jpg"));
form.replacePushbuttonField("imgPush", ad.getField());
```